# Observable.onSubscribe equivalent in RxJs

Tags: rxjs

In RxJava, there is [Observable.OnSubscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.OnSubscribe.html) which will call your action when something subscribes to the observable.

Is there an equivalent in RxJs?

---

*It seems as though they've taken the page down since asking this question.  Google's cached version [lives here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VddYHdNcPaUJ:reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.OnSubscribe.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).*

Comment: I've never seen/needed it and a quick search didn't find anything, though I don't know for sure - so I'll just post this as a comment

Comment: I searched as well, but came up with nothing.  I just find it odd that it exists in RxJava and not RxJs.  I kept my specific scenario out of the question as I feel this is a stronger question by itself.  I think the reason I need something like it is just due to bad design, unfortunately.

Comment: It is definitely useful for debug and logging purposes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This function is easily implemented by composition of the existing functions of RxJs5.

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.doOnSubscribe = function (onSubscribe) {
  return Rx.Observable.empty()
    .do(null,null, onSubscribe)
    .concat(this);
};

Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
  .doOnSubscribe(() => console.log('subscribed to stream'))
  .subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.log('completed'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

When downstream subscribes to the `doOnSubscribe` we first emit an empty observable and use the `.do()` onComplete callback as `doOnSubscribe`. Then we `.concat()` the upstream to this and return this modified stream.

Answer (score 14):

Really like Mark's answer, but if you're using `rxjs` version 5 or later, I'd prefer using pure functions instead of patching the prototype.

### Update:

Implemented without `empty` `concat` hack using `defer` as suggested by Ray

```typescript
import {defer} from 'rxjs/observable/defer';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

/** Example
import {from} from 'rxjs/observable/from';

from([1, 2, 3])
    .pipe(doOnSubscribe(() => console.log('subscribed to stream')))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x), null, () => console.log('completed'));
*/

export function doOnSubscribe<T>(onSubscribe: () => void): (source: Observable<T>) =>  Observable<T> {
    return function inner(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
        return defer(() => {
          onSubscribe();
          return source;
        });
    };
}
```

https://gist.github.com/evxn/750702f7c8e8d5a32c7b53167fe14d8d

### Original Answer:

```typescript
import {empty} from 'rxjs/observable/empty';
import {concat, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

/** Example
import {from} from 'rxjs/observable/from';
from([1, 2, 3])
    .pipe(doOnSubscribe(() => console.log('subscribed to stream')))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x), null, () => console.log('completed'));
*/

export function doOnSubscribe<T>(callback: () => void): (source: Observable<T>) =>  Observable<T> {
    return function inner(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
        return empty().pipe(
            tap(null, null, callback),
            concat<T>(source)
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another example that builds on Mark's answer is to use the factory functions:

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.doOnSubscribe = function(onSubscribe) {
  const source = this; 
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
      onSubscribe();
      return source;
  });
}
```