# rxjs operator to define logic after subscribe call

Tags: rxjs

```
    const source = Rx.Observable.of(1);

    const example = source
      .do(val => console.log('do called'));
    example.subscribe(val => console.log('subscribe called'));

    //Output :
    do called
    subscribe called
```

This exemple shows that `do` is executed before `subscribe`.

Which operator do I need to use to define logic ***after*** `subscribe` is executed ?

I need this to define logic one time and that must be executed after each subscribe call that helps also to respect SRP (Single responsibility Principle) an example is to handle caching logic in interceptor using some kind of specific operator that I am looking for and subscribe in services

Comment: What is it you would like to do after the `subscribe` is executed? Could you not just do it within the `subscribe` complete method? [Angular Observable Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SA25mG?p=preview)

Comment: I need to do it separately to respect SRP (Single responsibility Principle) an example is to handle caching logic in interceptor using do and subscribe in services

Comment: Subscribe is a stream of values, there is no operator that executes after receiving  each value. But the subscribe receives three parameters, the last parameter is a function that is executed before the observable is completed. But try Observable.from([1,2,3]) instead of(1) to see the behaviour.

Comment: subscribe is the end of a rxjs stream pipeline...

Comment: You don't need special operators to program according to SRP. Just separate your logic by function, and call those functions in `subscribe` as @P.Moloney said.

Comment: Something like this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883339/observable-onsubscribe-equivalent-in-rxjs

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle an Interceptor is as follows, it may help if I understand your requirements correctly.

```
...
private interceptor(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable
        .map(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            //handle Specific Error
            return Observable.throw(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            //After the request;
            console.info("After the Request")
        });
}

protected get(req: getHttpParams): Observable<Response> {
    return this.interceptor(this.httpClient.get(`${path}/${String(req.id)}`, req.options));
}
...
```

I would also recommend taking a look at [Angular 5's in-built interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) for `http` requests specifically